# Full height div not stretching

Tags: html, layout, height, css

Hi there I have been working on a website for quite some time now, improving code etc. I have just noticed that, on smaller screens, the height of the white background does not stretch past all of the content.

Setting `min-height: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` do not seem to solve it, do you think this could be down to the fact that a lot of the content is floating?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your `div.container`, remove `height: 100%` and add `overflow: auto`.

Comment: That almost did it, after adding `min-height: 100%;` to your suggestion it worked! Any suggestion on getting `min-height: 100%;` working in IE < 7 though?

Comment: @Wolfy87: `min-height` does not work on IE<7. IE<7 treats `height` in the way `min-height` is supposed to work, so for those browsers you should be able to just use `height`. However you'll need to do some browser detection and/or hacks to get it to use either `min-height` or `height` depending on the browser. Given that IE6 now has less than 3% market share, it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: @Wolfy87: I didn't consider IE6 when I was answering. If you are trying to make the site work in IE6, you might want to check [this page](http://www.astute.co.uk/buy-electronic-components.htm), it doesn't look correct. Are you sure you need `min-height:100%`? The site looks fine to me.

Comment: I just ran it through IE 6 on Adobe BrowserLab and it looked fine. So yeah, for the first time ever I am going to leave IE 6 behind.

Comment: @thirtydot If you use firebug and take out the `min-height` you will see that the page snaps up to the footer, I need it to go to the bottom, also, that page looks fine to me?

Comment: @thirtydot OH! I see, in IE 6 it falls to pieces. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @thirtydot I have just changed a couple of bits, it looks good now, how is it looking for you?

Comment: @Wolfy87: It looks correct to me. Even [that page](http://www.astute.co.uk/buy-electronic-components.htm) looks correct in IE6 now, good job.

Comment: @thirtydot Sweet, thanks for taking a look, I really need to get an XP virtual box on my MacBook, I keep having to borrow other peoples PCs in the office. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove "height: 100%" from the container, "float: left" from the footer and add "clear:both" to the footer. This will clear all the floats in the container and the background color of the container will be visible all the way down the page, regardless of the browser size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline-block` to main `div` , like:-

```
div.container{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting overflow:hidden; on the container that you want to clear under the rest of the content

Comment: But `overflow: hidden;` will do what it says on the tin, hide the overflowing content. I need it to be pushed down by this content, I was thinking more along the lines of a clear fix but I haven't managed to get that working yet either.

Comment: overflow:hidden can also be used to clear content - working in a similar way to .container:after { clear:both } http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I see, thanks for that, even though it is working now that is really helpful.